# Youtube Data API- HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

When I want to use the YouTube Data API to upload a video, it thrown the exceoption 401, however my Credential
have the scope of

```
upload("`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`").
```

I have enabled  the API in the Google Developer Console. How can I fix this I am very confused.

[image: my api console]

## my code

2020-06-18 17:28:18.007  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport:

-------------- REQUEST  --------------

POST `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`

Accept-Encoding: gzip

User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.23.0 (gzip)

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Content-Length: 269

2020-06-18 17:28:18.007  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport: 
curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.23.0 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' --
'`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`' << $$$

2020-06-18 17:28:18.929  INFO 26088 --- [ main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : Total: 269 bytes

2020-06-18 17:28:18.929  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport: grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=...&client_id=...&client_secret=...

2020-06-18 17:28:19.153  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport:
 -------------- RESPONSE --------------

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Alt-Svc: h3-28=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

Cache-Control: private
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Referer
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 09:28:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

2020-06-18 17:28:19.175  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : Total: 585 bytes

2020-06-18 17:28:19.176  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : {
  "access_token": "...",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload** https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification.verify_only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/manufacturercenter`",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}

2020-06-18 17:28:22.490  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : Total: 144 bytes

2020-06-18 17:28:22.492  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : {"snippet":{"categoryId":"22","description":"Description of uploaded video.","title":"Test video upload."},"status":{"privacyStatus":"private"}}

2020-06-18 17:28:22.493  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport:
 -------------- REQUEST  --------------

POST

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?access_token=...&part=snippet&part=status&uploadType=resumable
```

Accept-Encoding: gzip

User-Agent: ADAM Google-API-Java-Client/1.30.9 Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.23.0 (gzip)

x-goog-api-client: gl-java/1.8.0 gdcl/1.30.9 windows-10/10.0

x-upload-content-type: application/octet-stream

x-upload-content-length: 4969741

Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 125

2020-06-18 17:28:22.494  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   :
 curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: ADAM Google-API-Java-Client/1.30.9 Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.23.0 (gzip)' -H 'x-goog-api-client: gl-java/1.8.0 gdcl/1.30.9 windows-10/10.0' -H 'x-upload-content-type: application/octet-stream' -H 'x-upload-content-length: 4969741' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Content-Encoding: gzip' -d '@-' 
-- '`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?access_token=...&part=snippet&part=status&uploadType=resumable`' << $$$

2020-06-18 17:28:22.900  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : Total: 144 bytes

2020-06-18 17:28:22.902  INFO 26088 --- [ main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : {"snippet":{"categoryId":"22","description":"Description of uploaded video.","title":"Test video upload."},"status":{"privacyStatus":"private"}}

2020-06-18 17:28:23.322  INFO 26088 --- [main] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   :
 -------------- RESPONSE --------------

**HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized**

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Warning: 214 UploadServer gzipped

Alt-Svc: h3-28=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

Cache-Control: private

Server: UploadServer

Content-Encoding: gzip

X-GUploader-UploadID: AAANsUn5M53nz45hqEKbbVNqSMaAIK9KOfY53I0TeGum-0GkPUE9YkgpeF4tDIL3x973oQwG_JXGnWljYPH9uQBQFQ

Vary: Referer

Vary: X-Origin

Vary: Origin

Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 09:28:23 GMT

Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

```
// You need to set this value for your code to compile.
    // For example: ... DEVELOPER_KEY = "YOUR ACTUAL KEY";
    private static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "...";
    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, null)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "ADAM";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();



    @Test
    public void test1()
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {
        YouTube youtubeService = getService();
        Credential credential = GoogleAuthenticationUtil.getCredential("...");
        // Define the Video object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
        Video video = new Video();
        String accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
        // Add the snippet object property to the Video object.
        VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        snippet.setCategoryId("22");
        snippet.setDescription("Description of uploaded video.");
        snippet.setTitle("Test video upload.");
        video.setSnippet(snippet);

        // Add the status object property to the Video object.
        VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
        status.setPrivacyStatus("private");
        video.setStatus(status);

        // TODO: For this request to work, you must replace "YOUR_FILE"
        //       with a pointer to the actual file you are uploading.
        //       The maximum file size for this operation is 137438953472.
        File mediaFile = new File("E:\\57086854184752465.mp4");
        InputStreamContent mediaContent =
                new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream",
                        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mediaFile)));
        mediaContent.setLength(mediaFile.length());

        // Define and execute the API request
        YouTube.Videos.Insert request = youtubeService.videos()
                .insert(Arrays.asList("snippet", "status"), video, mediaContent);
        Video response = request.setAccessToken(accessToken).execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you loading the client secrete json file?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see where you are loading the client secret json file. You apear to only load a api key.

```
  /**
   * Initializes an authorized YouTube service object.
   *
   * @return The YouTube service object.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException
   */
  private static YouTube initializeAnalyticsReporting() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

    // Load client secrets.
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(HelloYouTube.class
            .getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_RESOURCE)));

    // Set up authorization code flow for all authorization scopes.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
        .Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
            YouTubeScopes.all()).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
        .build();

    // Authorize.
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
        new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    // Construct the YouTube service object.
    return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }
```

Comment: {
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.quota",
    "message" : "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>.",
    "reason" : "quotaExceeded",
    "debugInfo" : "Code: 8; Description: ?metric=youtube.googleapis.com/default&limit=defaultPerDayPerProject&qs_error_code=INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS"
  } ],
  "message" : "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>."
}

Comment: i just  request 22 times today ,why it thown this exception?

Comment: @许伦杰 you need to check the quota calculator https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost